# Non-ascii characters on reading a CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv, character-encoding

I have a big CSV file (~45MB) with about 350.000 rows and 6 columns.

When I used this code in Python:

```
data = open("myextract.csv")
reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=",")

for r in reader:
    #mystuff
```

Only 260.000 rows were parsed. I didn't have any error or a clue. But, during an investigation, I saw that a few columns have non-ascii characters like small arrows.(I cannot even copy-paste it here)

What I found is that if the columns text is like this

`blah blah blah -the arrow- another blah blah`

Then everything after the -arrow- stripped out with a few rows after that. But the same row until the arrow was parsed and stored without a problem.

So, any clue how to work with this?

Comment: Did you try editing `myextract.csv` in a text editor and save as UTF-8?

Comment: Generally speaking, non-ASCII data *usually* should not result in the `csv.reader` to stop parsing prematurely. Can you get to such a line in Python and show us what `print repr(line)` looks like? That'll encode the line in such a way we can reproduce the data exactly without causing all sorts of glyph problems for you.

Comment: @Selcuk I tried it before, but it messed up my whole file, since it change the encoding of many entries.

Comment: If you can give us sample data then we can try to solve the problem. As @MartijnPieters mention, csvreader not stops parsing if its non-ASCII character in `csv` file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried it and the line stop in that character. Without even finishing the line with the rest columns.